# What's the difference between async and job in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

js newbie here!

I have read [the description of job](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#job) but still quite confuse about the difference with using `this.async(function(){...}, 500)`, is clearing `this.toastTimeout1` first(I haven't written any code to 'delay some tasks' before and not familiar with this tech)? And when I am reading `core-tooltip.html`, I found a piece of code:

```
   labelChanged: function(oldVal, newVal) {
     this.job('positionJob', this.setPosition);
   },
```

Why not call `this.serPosition` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` simply performs a task after a time period has elapsed.

`job` is similar, but if `job` is called again with the same job-name before the time period has elapsed, the timer is reset.

In the example above, if `labelChanged` is called multiple times in quick succession, `job` makes sure the `setPosition` callback is called only once.

Sometimes what `job` does is called [debouncing](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/). Hrm, maybe we should call it *debounce*.

Comment: As of Polymer 1.0, `job` has been renamed to `debounce`.